# Append to tbody using AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am just trying to append to my html tbody tag using ajax call.
My code looks like this. The data is just a demo data i hooked up to my DB.

C#

```
public static string GetEmployee()
    {
        List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
                emp.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                emp.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                emp.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                lstEmployee.Add(emp);
            }
        }

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstEmployee);
        return json; 

    }
```

HTML

```
<table id="employees" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My Json object

```
[
{"Id":1,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"abc","Email":""},
{"Id":2,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"abc","Email":""},
{"Id":3,"FirstName":"Phillip","LastName":"abc","Email":""},
{"Id":4,"FirstName":"Ken","LastName":"abc","Email":""},
{"Id":5,"FirstName":"Miranda","LastName":"abc","Email":""},
{"Id":6,"FirstName":"Liv","LastName":"abc","Email":""}
]
```

My Ajax Call here is the issue . Somehow i am not able to figure out how to iterate through the response data.
**What I Get**

- FirstName LastName  Email
  undefined undefined undefined

Only one row of undefined. Not sure what i am doing wrong as i dont see any error in console log.

```
function loadEmployees() {   
            
            var tboby = $('#employees tbody');
            tboby.empty(); //clear the data               

            //ajax call to cs file
            $.ajax({
                url: "jqueryDialogSaveToDB.aspx/GetEmployee",
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).each(function () {
                        var tr = $('<tr></tr>')
                        tr.append('<td>' + this.FirstName + '</td>')
                        tr.append('<td>' + this.LastName + '</td>')
                        tr.append('<td>' + this.Email + '</td>')
                        tboby.append(tr);
                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("data failure" + response.data);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Update**
When i console log it this is my response Json Object from backend.
[image]
When i try to

```
JSON.parse(data); // this is json object coming in from backend
```

I get the error message as it thinks the response object is Undefined.
Thank you for having a look.

Comment: Shouldn't really wrap the array in `$()`. Try `$.each(data, function(i, obj){ .... obj.FirstName.... })`

Comment: Also inspect the actual response to make sure you don't have an empty object in the array for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);                       
                    $.each(response, function (i, obj) {
                        //console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
                        var arrVal = JSON.parse(obj);
                        for (var i = 0; i < arrVal.length; i++) {                               
                            var tr = $('<tr></tr>')
                            tr.append('<td>' + arrVal[i]["FirstName"] + '</td>')
                            tr.append('<td>' + arrVal[i]["LastName"] + '</td>')
                            tr.append('<td>' + arrVal[i]["Email"] + '</td>')
                            tboby.append(tr);
                        }
                    });                        
                 },
```

What i did was console.log it every time and see what my response object looks like. Since it was throwing error when i, JSON.parse(response).I looped through it and then parsed it. After that it was easy. Got a array list and had to set it in the td and tr and append to tbody to get my result.

If there is a better answer i will take it . I still will leave this question up for grabs . Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

The data you receive is in a string format. You need to parse it to json before working with it:

```
success: function (json) {

                var data = JSON.parse(json);

                // Possibly use $(data.content) instead of $(data) below
                $(data).each(function () {
                    var tr = $('<tr></tr>')
                    tr.append('<td>' + this.FirstName + '</td>')
                    tr.append('<td>' + this.LastName + '</td>')
                    tr.append('<td>' + this.Email + '</td>')
                    tboby.append(tr);
                });
            }
```

Comment: Not needed. Setting `dataType:'json'` as OP has done returns parsed data to callbacks

Comment: I have updated my question. Json.parse throws a error as it thinks the object is undefined as the data is wrapped around d variable. I have console.log(response); and then tried to parse it where i get the error as per screen shot above.